# Retornar elemento a posição inicial em hover css

Tags: css, css-animations, scss

Estou fazendo uma animação em uma logo, onde cada letra vai para um lado e quando eu passar o mouse na div onde ela está, todas as letras devem voltar ao valor inicial, assim formando a logo.
Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que como estou utilizando animation para movimentar cada letra, quando eu passo o mouse em cima da div, eu preciso remover esse animation, só que eu preciso que isso seja feito de uma maneira suave, na mesma velocidade em que a letra está se mexendo, só que quando eu removo, a letra se "teletransporta" para o lugar dela.

Há alguma maneira de eu remover o animation no hover só que sem que seja sem esta forma brusca que fica atualmente quando passa o mouse na div?

Segue exemplo para melhor entendimento

```css
.pai {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.pai img {
  max-width: 50px;
  top: 150px;
}
.one {position: absolute}
.two {position: absolute;left:50px}
.three {position: absolute;left:100px; animation: floating-c 5s infinite;}
@keyframes floating-c {
    0% {
      margin-top: -150px;
      margin-left: -150px;
      filter:blur(5px);
    }
    50% {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      filter:blur(0px);
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: -150px;
      margin-left: -150px;
      filter:blur(5px);
    }
  }
  .three:hover {
    animation: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <img class="one" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/142577/isolated/preview/6f56190e2f5224ce831a6dd08be708b1-um-isotipo-de-origami-de-carta-by-vexels.png">
  <img
  class="two"
  src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/37/37502.png">
  <img
  class="three"
  src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/17/07/10/208ed1d531fd30c78cd184c2e5167370.jpg">
</div>
```

Segue link do pen: https://codepen.io/maukruger/pen/RwbajVL?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Olá eu apenas fiz umas modificações porém não consegui uma opção para capturar o movimento do objeto animado e continuar a partir dele, mas da uma olhada pra ver se já te atende.

```css
.pai {
 background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 &:hover {
   .three {
     animation: floating-d 5s;
   }
 }
}
.pai img {
  max-width: 50px;
  top: 150px;
}
.one {position: absolute}
.two {position: absolute;left:50px}
.three {position: absolute;left:100px; animation: floating-c 5s infinite;}
@keyframes floating-c {
    0% {
      margin-top: -150px;
      margin-left: -150px;
      filter:blur(5px);
    }
    50% {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      filter:blur(0px);
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: -150px;
      margin-left: -150px;
      filter:blur(5px);
    }
  }
@keyframes floating-d {
    0% {
      margin-top: -150px;
      margin-left: -150px;
      filter:blur(5px);
    }
 
    50% {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      filter:blur(0px);
    }
   
  }
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <img class="one" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/142577/isolated/preview/6f56190e2f5224ce831a6dd08be708b1-um-isotipo-de-origami-de-carta-by-vexels.png">
  <img
  class="two"
  src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/37/37502.png">
  <img
  class="three"
  src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/17/07/10/208ed1d531fd30c78cd184c2e5167370.jpg">
</div>
```